# How to build primeng from source code after cloning

Tags: angular, build, compilation, angular-cli, primeng

I struggled a bit to build primeng from source, after checking the doc of angular-cli (spoiler: didn't help, they don't follow the standard)
I tried all these

```
ng build
ng build -c production
... --aot
... --prod
...
```

then read the code, and some forum questions, I found the following

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
@ShaneCoder is the correct one now

Old answer: < 9.x.x
Here are the steps:

```
gulp clean
gulp build-assets
gulp build-exports
tsc --build tsconfig-release.json
npm pack
```

you can the create a release on github, and refrence it using it's URL in your package.json instead of the version number:
ex: `https://github.com/<YOUR_USERNAME>/primeng/releases/download/8.0.0-rc2/primeng-8.0.0-rc.2-SNAPSHOT.tgz`...

Answer (score 1):

The build process has changed to use `ng-packagr` in primeng 9.  This method was confirmed in primeng 10.  To build:

```
npm install ng-packager --save-dev
npm run build-lib
```

I haven't built version 9 using `ng-packagr`.  Should be the same according to this [link](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/8057).

Answer (score 0):

```
ng build --project primeng-library
```

and add these two lines to the [production] section in the .browserslistrc file:

```
not ios_saf 15.2-15.3
not safari 15.2-15.3
```